# Querying the Audit Log through Database [SQL Server]

Tags: sql-server, enterprise-architect

I would like to take the Audit History provided by Enterprise Architect and create a SQL query to report through a BI tool that will allow myself and other users to search the history of an object but I am having a little trouble understanding the audit table: t_snapshot.

From what I can tell, t_snapshot has a Style column that contains "INSERT," "UPDATE," and "DELETE" which would tell me what is happening and the Notes column can tell me what object it is referencing but so far I've only been able to get a partial picture. What I have not been able to deduce is when any event occurred or which user made the change.

If anyone has encountered this problem in the past, your input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know whether you really want to touch that.

There's a column called `BinContent` which contains what you are looking for. It looks like

```
<LogItem><Row Number="0"><Column Name="object_id"><Old Value="1797"/><New Value="1797"/></Column><Column Name="name"><Old Value="CB"/><New Value="CBc"/></Column><Column Name="modifieddate"><Old Value="07.12.2018"/><New Value="11.12.2018"/></Column><appliesTo><Element Type="Action"/></appliesTo></Row><Details User="Thomas" DateTime="2018-12-11 08:22:59"/></LogItem>
```

So basically some XML describing the change including the plain text user name.

The `bincontent` column(s) are actually zips which contain a single file `str.dat` holding the above information.

Good luck.

Comment: See my addition above.

Comment: Hu. I have a Perl program to read the tables. But you are right. There is probably no way to get it from SQL except you can hack the database to unzip data.